# routing differences through zuul proxy with eureka

Tags: proxy, routes, netflix-zuul

I have two machines (with same application) register to eureka server.
all requests to these services are through zuul proxy.

**my application.properties of my backend services is:**

```
spring.application.name=core
```

**my application.properties of my zuul proxy is:**

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders=Set-Cookie

zuul.routes.address.path=/to-address/**
zuul.routes.address.url=http://localhost:8888

zuul.routes.service.path=/by-service/**
zuul.routes.service.url=CORE
```

I have two questions:

1. All three request below are working, which one should I use?
   What is the difference with upper case and lower case?

   - http://localhost:9090/api/by-service/customer/1
   - http://localhost:9090/api/core/customer/1
   - http://localhost:9090/api/CORE/customer/1
2. When I call the service in the following way:

   http://localhost:9090/api/to-address/customer/1

   I noticed that a new session is being created by my core server, which force my user to login again. Any idea why?

As you can see it's the same method (same filter, same application...) with just a routing difference.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `req.getRequestedSessionId()` instead of `req.getSession().getId()`.